# @torch.no_grad equivalent in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

In pytorch, we can define @torch.no_grad before a function in class(nn.Module) to stop gradient, does tensorflow has some similar function?

I found a function

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
 
  with tape.stop_recording():
```

in tensorflow, but I am struggled with how to properly feed the tape into the model

Comment: You might be looking for [tf.stop_gradient](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient)

Comment: @Lescurel but it seems that stop_gradient can only be used for a tensor instead of a function

Comment: TensorFlow doesn't compute gradient while using `predict` or if you are predicting using `model` then use `model(x , training=False)`